# selectable and movable shapes in html5

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg

I am creating a dynamic, interactive network diagram with php, javascript and either Canvas or SVG

However, with canvas, I don't know how to make each object selectable. i don't want to use the hidden canvas and to detect if a mouse is on an object, because I will have lots of intersecting objects and having lots of layers of canvas will be messy.

I don't know anything about SVG.

Would SVG serves the purpose better? or what is a canvas solution to this.

Comment: For a canvas abstraction, take a look at [fabric.js](http://kangax.github.com/fabric.js/test/demo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One advantage of SVG is that it has concrete DOM objects representing the shapes in the drawing, so you automatically get a lot of mouse event handling and event bubbling.

Alternatively, you could use [EaselJS](http://easeljs.com/), which provides a pretty robust display-list, freeing you from managing hidden canvases.

[image: EaselJS]

Comment: it seems EaselJS is trying to achieve a lot of things SVG is already doing..why should I use a new addon while there have been so much support for SVG already? I am just trying to figure out the arguments for both sides

Comment: You have much richer control of the final composition using canvas. Graphically-rich bitmaps are handled with no additional overhead. With SVG, to achieve the same look you might have to layer a number of shapes and use complex gradients. Canvas-based solutions can also be more responsive since there is no event-bubbling through all SVGs concrete elements.

Answer (score 0):

There are some projects for building diagrams and graphics already. You could try [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) which is svg based, so it should be ie compatible as well.

Comment: I heard about Raphael...but I also heard there isn't a way to accept input (like w/ html form) through Raphael, and feeds back into php then my DB...I need the users be able to modify the network diagram and the data goes back into php...is that possible with Raphael

Answer (score 0):

I assume by "the hidden canvas" you mean my tutorial. It will still work with multiple objects and multiple layers, you just need to paint them in the proper z-order.

There are of course much faster (but more sophisticated) ways.

If you don't want to deal with it, SVG has all the object selection built in. Give Raphael a try as Zlatev suggests. If the performance gets too bad (Too many objects) you will have to switch to canvas, so it really depends on your number of nodes/links in your diagrams.

You will have to take care of sending data to your server (in whatever way you prefer) yourself though. There's nothing built into SVG/Canvas/Raphael that will do it for you.

Comment: At what point would SVG slows down due to too many nodes, links. Lets say, I will could have hundreds of nodes..will it?